Slow CDN request
My root config project contains default scripts requests (import-map-override, system, amd) inside index.ejs, but they are loading about 10 seconds. Is there way to store them locally and call this files instead of http requests?
I tried storing them locally near the index.ejs, but I got 404 error

In a web application, there is no "local".  Everything comes from a download.  What one normally does is bundle things (generally speaking), using tools like Vite and webpack.  You could switch CDN's, or you could serve it yourself if you download the entirety of the package and copy it over to your HTTP server.
